# If I search for anything in Input tag, If I have that data it has to show that otherwise it has to show no results

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React project, In that project I iterate An Array of objects. Above that I have input tag so for what I am strugling is If I type name tom in input tag then only tom has to show other data has to hide. ANd If I type name that is not there in array of objects then it has to show now results

This is employs.json

```
[
    {
        "id": "0",
        "name": "tom",
        "location": "warsaw"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "lucas",
        "location": "sanfrancisco"
    },{
        "id": "2",
        "name": "williams",
        "location": "willington"
    },{
        "id": "3",
        "name": "mark",
        "location": "toronto"
    },{
        "id": "4",
        "name": "jerry",
        "location": "moscow"
    },{
        "id": "5",
        "name": "john",
        "location": "canberra"
    },{
        "id": "6",
        "name": "shyam",
        "location": "newyork"
    },{
        "id": "7",
        "name": "lucas",
        "location": "Behrain"
    },{
        "id": "8",
        "name": "ajay",
        "location": "bejing"
    },{
        "id": "9",
        "name": "shekar",
        "location": "cargo"
    },{
        "id": "10",
        "name": "vipin",
        "location": "paris"
    }
]
```

This is App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Employs from './API/employs.json'
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="Employee-list">
      <label>Search Employee</label>
      <input placeholder="Search Employee" style={{ color: 'white' }} type="text" id="ser" />
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Location</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {Employs.map((data, index) =>
            <tr key={index}>
              <td>{data.name}</td>
              <td>{data.location}</td>
            </tr>

          )}
        </tbody>

        <tfoot >
        </tfoot>

      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is App.css

```
body {
background-color: #d2d2d2;
display: grid;
justify-content: center;
font-family: 'open sans';
}

.Employee-list {
display: grid;
}

.Employee-list table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border: 1px solid #626a80;
}

.Employee-list thead, .Employee-list tfoot {
color: #ffffff;
}

.Employee-list tbody, .Employee-list p{
color: #ffffff;
}

::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
color: white;
opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
}

.Employee-list th, .Employee-list td {
border: 1px solid #626a80;
padding: 5px;
}

.Employee-list th {
background-color: #eb008c;
}

.Employee-list th:first-child {
width: 300px;
}

.Employee-list th:last-child {
width: 100px;
}

.Employee-list tr:nth-child(2n) {
background-color: #21242c;
}

.Employee-list tr:nth-child(2n+1) {
background-color: #2a2f3d;
}

.Employee-list td:last-child {
text-align: right;
}

.Employee-list input {
box-sizing: border-box;;
margin-bottom: 5px;
padding: 3px 8px;
background-color: #eb008c;
color: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #eb008c;
border-radius: 4px;
line-height: 24px;
outline: none;
}
```

If you have any questions please put a comment thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use React's "useState" here, so it would be something like this:

```
    import React, {useState} from 'react';
        import Employs from './API/employs.json'
        import './App.css';
        
        function App() {
            const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
            return (
                <div className="Employee-list">
                    <label>Search Employee</label>
                    <input placeholder="Search Employee" style={{ color: 'white' }} type="text" id="ser" value={search} onChange={e => setSearch(e.target.value)}/>
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Location</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {Employs.filter((a) => a.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1).map((data, index) =>
                            <tr key={index}>
                                <td>{data.name}</td>
                                <td>{data.location}</td>
                            </tr>
        
                        )}
                        </tbody>
        
                        <tfoot >
                        </tfoot>
        
                    </table>
                </div>
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OlVkYnVXPl0&t=322s? You need to take your search value and you must use indexOf() or includes() method.